# MySQL query to list all the employees whose name starts and ends with same character (case-sensitive)

Tags: mysql

I have one table with name "Employee" with column Id as "Name". How to get rows of employee name whose name start and end with same character (case-sensitive) in MySQL.

Example: 
 - anna 
 - ANITHA 
 - ANNA 
 - DAViD

Comment: you should explain what you have tried doing and we may help getting you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM `Employee` WHERE 
BINARY LEFT(name, 1) = RIGHT(name, 1);

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary

Comment: @mrinfo inf, if it is relevant to your question,pls accept it.